# For $p \ge 1$, demonstrate that $\log(x) \in L^{p}((0,1],\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces

Let, $f(x) = \log(x)$. We have that,
$$\vert\vert f \vert\vert_{p} = (\int_{(0,1]}|f(x)|^p ~ d\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
By the monotone convergence theorem and that the Lebesgue integral is equal to the Riemann integral on a compact interval with a bounded function, we can conclude that:
$$\int_{(0,1]} |\log(x)|^p ~ d\mu = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int^{1}_{\frac{1}{n}}|\log(x)|^p ~ dx.$$
Observe that,
$$\lim_{u \rightarrow - \infty } |u|^p e^{u} = 0.$$
Hence, there exists a $C > 0$ such that:
$$|u|^p e^{u} \le C, ~ ~ \forall u \in [0,-\infty).$$
Let, $x  = e^{2u}$, and we obtain that, $\frac{dx}{du} = 2e^{2u}.$
Hence,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int^{1}_{\frac{1}{n}}|\log(x)|^p ~ dx \le K \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{0}_{\frac{-ln(n)}{2}}e^{u} ~ du .$$
Where $K$ is some constant greater than zero consisting of $C$ times other constant terms. Thus,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{0}_{\frac{-ln(n)}{2}}e^{u} ~ du  < \infty  \implies f \in L^{p}((0,1],\mu).$$

Does my proof look good? Thanks.

Comment: With the substitution $u = -\log(x)$, the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{\infty}u^pe^{-u}\,du$.

Comment: @Mason, I see that is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @Mason . Or let $x=1/y$ and we have $\int_1^{\infty}y^{-2}(\log y)^pdy.$